# Admob problem - Android

Tags: android, admob

I'm building an Android app. I'm trying to use Admob, but I have some problems with it. I followed the guide on their sites, and looked for answers in the web, but couldn't find an answer.

My problem is that I can't see any ads.
In the log I see the following -

> 04-22 16:47:06.660: INFO/Ads(28251):
>   onFailedToReceiveAd(No ad to show.)

I see this message both in test mode in and regular mode.
I can see test ads in the emulator though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no Ad to show, there is no ad to show. this doesn't mean it isn't working.  AdMob does not always show ads, there has to be something available.  if it is working on the emulator, you have successfully implemented AdMob into your application.

Comment: But it doesn't work on my phone on test mode as well...I don't think it's normal.

Comment: onFailedToReceiveAd(No ad to show.) is NOT an error. it just means the AdMob service has no ad to show at this time.  test ads will not work on an actual device.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main.xml`, add:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="a14ed7ed1b71bc0"
                       ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

and in your manifest add into application tag:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Your app must includes Google AdMob Ads Sdk 431.jar